# Simple calculator example using array to store input values

Tags: javascript, arrays

The input values are stored in an array, the below loop is to calculate the final result, by looping through the array and appending the operators and numbers to a variable which is then evaluated.

```
privateCalculate = function () {
    var total;

    for(i = 0; i < init.sequence.length; i++) {
        if(init.sequence[i] === "+" || init.sequence[i] === "-" ||
           init.sequence[i] === "*" || init.sequence[i] === "/" ||
           init.sequence[i] === "(" || init.sequence[i] === ")") 
        {
            total += init.sequence[i];
        } else {
            init.sequence[i] = parseFloat(init.sequence[i]);

            total += init.sequence[i];
        }

    }

    console.log(eval(total));
    //console.log((parseFloat(1)+parseFloat(2))/parseFloat(2));
},
```

The function produces `"NaN"`

Comment: please print the content of `init.sequence`

Comment: ["5", "+", "5"], the if logic is intended to convert "5" to 5

Comment: Drop the `parseFloat`, your strings will be converted to ints with `eval` anyway

Comment: the numbers are being converted back to strings anyway, so this makes no sense. just join the values `total=init.sequence.join("")`

Comment: What??? Sorry but if you have `var arr = ["10","+","5","-","2","*","3"]` >>> this is all you need: `eval(arr.join(""))`

Answer (score 1):

You said your input is: `["5","+","5"]` 
You don't need to parse it, because `eval`takes as parameter a `String`

Just do this:

```
var inputArray = ["5","+","5"];
eval(inputArray.join('')) // -> 10
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I said in comments. Though be careful not to allow global access to the `eval` or trough function arguments/ callbacks etc. In that case it could be exploited to attacks.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan two dumb guys, one though :)

Comment: Yes, `eval` is a **"feature"** unless you knew it :D